# Rename Firebase Analytics Log Event

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I currently have a production app using Firebase Analytics events, some of the event names no longer make sense and I would like to rename them.

Is it possible to rename a Firebase Analytics log event?

For instance, rename `My_Event` to `My_New_Event`

```
Analytics.logEvent("My_Event", parameters: nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to change historical analytics data. So while you can start logging a new name for the same event at any point, you will then have to look for both events in the Google Analytics and Firebase dashboards.

If you're using the BigQuery integration, you can implement the old name as an alias in your queries. But no such functionality exists in the Google Analytics or Firebase dashboards that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question: "Is it possible to rename a Firebase Analytics log event?"  The answer is yes if you have edit permissions for your Google Analytics 4 property.

In Firebase Analytics click Events, the Modify Event button, and then the Create button.  Follow the guidance from [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX2rBgFfAJo) to rename the event, for example:

[image]

Comment: Your instructions and the given video are unclear if you can use that to actually modify the event name or to create a new event which will be triggered by certain conditions (when the old event is triggered, in our case) instead.